# What does the maximal basis for a Grothendieck topology look like?

Tags: sheaf-theory, topos-theory

There is the notion of *Grothendieck topology* on a category $\mathbf{C}$. This is a specific assignment of a collection $J(C)$ of sieves to each object $C\in \mathbf{C}$.

A *Grothendieck pretopology* or *basis for a Grothendieck topology* is a specific assignment of a collection $K(C)$ of covers for each object $C\in \mathbf{C}$. Such a basis *generates* a Grothendieck topology by
$$
J(C)=\{S=\{C_i\to C\}\mid \exists R\in K(C):R\subseteq S\}
$$
but there may exist many bases for one Grothendieck topology.

There is a *maximal basis* for a Grothendieck topology and I think this gives a one-to-one correspondence between Grothendieck topologies and maximal pretopologies.

> Given a Grothendieck pretopology $K$, how can I define a maximal pretopology $\mathbf{K}$ without mentioning Grothendieck topologies and sieves?

I tried
$$
\mathbf{K}(C)=\{\{D_k\to C\}_{k\in K}\mid \exists \{E_i\to C\}_{i\in I}\in K(C)\forall i\in I\exists k\in K:E_i\to D_k\to C\},
$$
is this right? Maybe this isn't a pretopology and I must intersect all pretopologies with the property after '$|$' instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's be clear about what we mean. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category, not necessarily small or with pullbacks. A **coverage** on $\mathcal{C}$ is a collection of families $K (C)$ of sinks on $C$ for each object $C$ of our category $\mathcal{C}$ satisfying this condition:

- For every sink $\mathfrak{U}$ in $K (C)$ and every morphism $g : D \to C$ in $\mathcal{C}$, there is some sink $\mathfrak{V}$ in $K (D)$ such that, for each morphism $h$ in $\mathfrak{V}$, the composite $g \circ h$ factors through some morphism in $\mathfrak{U}$. (More succinctly, the sink $\{ g \circ h : h \in \mathfrak{V} \}$ is subordinate to $\mathfrak{U}$.)

A **saturated coverage** on $\mathcal{C}$ is a coverage $K$ on $\mathcal{C}$ satisfying these additional conditions:

- For each object $C$, the singleton sink $\{ \textrm{id}_C : C \to C \}$ is in $K (C)$.
- Given any sink $\mathfrak{U}$ in $K (C)$ and any choice of sinks $\mathfrak{V}_f$ in $K (\operatorname{dom} f)$ for each $f$ in $\mathfrak{U}$, the family $\{ f \circ h : f \in \mathfrak{U}, h \in \mathfrak{V}_f \}$ is also in $K (C)$.
- Given $\mathfrak{V}$ in $K (C)$ and any sink $\mathfrak{U}$ on $C$, if $\mathfrak{V}$ is subordinate to $\mathfrak{U}$ (i.e. each morphism in $\mathfrak{V}$ factors through some morphism in $\mathfrak{U}$), then $\mathfrak{U}$ is already in $K (C)$.

Given a Grothendieck topology $J$ on $\mathcal{C}$, one can define a saturated coverage $K$ by setting
$$K (C) = \{ \mathfrak{U} : \mathfrak{U} \text{ is a sink on $C$ and generates a sieve in } J (C) \}$$
and conversely, given a saturated coverage $K$, one can define a Grothendieck topology $J$ by setting
$$J (C) = \{ \mathfrak{U} : \mathfrak{U} \text{ is a sieve on $C$ and is in } K (C) \}$$
and these constructions are mutually inverse.

Your question is how to cut Grothendieck topologies out of the picture. This is simple enough: given any Grothendieck pretopology $T$, we can build a saturated coverage $K$ as follows:
$$K (C) = \{ \mathfrak{U} : \mathfrak{U} \text{ is a sink on $C$ and, for some $\mathfrak{V}$ in $T (C)$, $\mathfrak{V}$ is subordinate to $\mathfrak{U}$ } \}$$
If I have not misread your symbolic formula, this is precisely the construction you have suggested. This is because the relation "$\mathfrak{V}$ is subordinate to $\mathfrak{U}$" is equivalent to "(the sieve generated by) $\mathfrak{V}$ is contained in the sieve generated by $\mathfrak{U}$", and it is well-known that the family of covering sieves in a Grothendieck topology is upward-closed.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful answer. If I get you right, my construction $\mathbf{K}$ is in fact a pretopology, right?

Comment: It is when the category $\mathcal{C}$ has pullbacks.

Comment: Is the pre-topology $\mathbf{K}$ (when $\mathcal{C}$ has pullbacks) also a Grothendieck topology, i.e. are the elements of $\mathbf{K}(C)$ actually sieves and satisfy the topology conditions?

Comment: @ZhenLin, I downvoted your answer by accident and cannot upvote it again. I wrote to a moderator to change that. Sorry.

Comment: No, $K$ is almost never a Grothendieck topology in this case.

Comment: Ok, I see, it isn't because each sieve is closed under precomposition, sorry. But isn't it that $J(C)\subset K(C)$? We have $\{D_k\to C\}\in K(C)\Leftrightarrow (\{D_k\to C\})\in J(C)$ where the brackets ''(,)'' denote the closure under precomposition. So in particular $(\{D_k\to C\})\in K(C)$, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, $J$ is contained in $K$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But then the formula of the OP for $K(C)$ seems not to be correct since it just requires, that for each covering in $K(C)$ there is a *covering* of the initial pre-topology (and not a sieve generated by some covering of the initial pre-topology) which refines it, correct? Very confusing...

Comment: I didn't describe how to construct $J$ from a _non-saturated_ pretopology. In fact, $J$ is defined to be the collection of all sieves containing a covering family.

Comment: I didn't mean your formula but the formula for $K(C)$ in the question of the OP.